# Why do I get "kotlin.Unit" error and how to fix it

Tags: kotlin

```
package com.example.codingisfun

fun main(){
    val phone1= MobilePhone("Android","Samsung","S30")
    val phone2= MobilePhone("IOS","Apple","Iphone 14")
}

class MobilePhone(osName: String, brand: String, model: String){
    private var battery= 30
    init {
        println("The phone $model from $brand uses $osName as its Operating System")
        println(chargeBattery(30))
        println(battery)
    }
    private fun chargeBattery(charged:Int){
        println("before charge:$battery,charged: $charged and now: ${battery+charged}")
        battery += charged
    }
}
```

When I run it it prints:

The phone S30 from Samsung uses Android as its Operating System
before charge:30,charged: 30 and now: 60
kotlin.Unit
60
The phone Iphone 14 from Apple uses IOS as its Operating System
before charge:30,charged: 30 and now: 60
kotlin.Unit
60

chargeBattery was assigned to 30 then I deleted it and use it on init still same how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "chargeBattery" has no return type defined and in Kotlin by default every function that do not define a return type returns the Unit type. Adding the Unit type to the method signature is optional but basically you could also define the method as:

```
fun chargeBattery(charged: Int): Unit { ... }
```

So when you are calling "println(chargeBattery(30))", you are effectively printing the returned type of the function, having your "before charge:$ba..." string printed is a side-effect of the execution of your function.

If you only wanted to print your string by using "println" you should have the "chargeBattery" method return your string like :

```
fun chargeBattery(charged: Int): String {
   val line = "before charge:$battery,charged: $charged and now: ${battery+charged}"
   battery += charged
   return line
}
```

And then by calling the "println(chargeBattery(30)", only the line would be printed.

Comment: Might also be worth adding that `Unit` (strictly `kotlin.Unit`) is a type with exactly one value, of the same name — and that value is what's being returned and printed.